Hubspot API Endpoint for Files Uploaded by Form Stopped Working Suddenly
The Hubspot API endpoint for "Get a file uploaded via form" stopped working for me all of a sudden after a long time of usage.
It now returns the HTML body of a login page, not an API response. You can re-create the error even using the cURL example on their page which should return an error due to the truncated key at the very least.
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer CKKW1...o1hpIM" -L "https://api.hubapi.com/form-integrations/v1/uploaded-files/signed-url-redirect/3828015845?portalId=101805458&sign=-nwOZ3hWZ3bsfiWT5QUlzQwczUU%3D&conversionId=5871a2ea-f800-4733-8133-40a2f6fd6bb2&filename=5871a2ea-f800-4733-8133-40a2f6fd6bb2-form_file_upload-test_file.txt"

This instead the long HTML...
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /><link rel="preconnect" href="https://static.hsappstatic.net" crossorigin="anonymous" /><title>HubSpot Login and Sign in</title><meta name="description" content="Sign into your HubSpot account through HubSpot&#x27;s login page. No login? Signup for a free account." /><link id="canonical-link" rel="canonical" /><script>document.getElementById("canonical-link").href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname</script><script>window.I18N_RENDERED_LANG = "en";  ....

I assume they changed something about authentication? But this "Bearer" auth method still works for other legacy endpoints.
Anyone have any clues where to start?

For anyone else banging their head against a wall, I used the new v3 "Get signed URL to access private file." api by just pulling the file ID out of the original v1 URL, and using it to request the new v3 url.
